# How to create Azure Monitor - Alerts for virtual machine using Azure .Net SDK or Powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-sdk-.net, azure-fluent-api

I want to create Azure Monitor - Alerts for virtual machine disk utilization, CPU usage etc.
So Is there any way or any Azure .net sdk which will help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor supports creating alerts in the Portal, with Azure CLI, and with Azure PowerShell (there are also some interactions using the REST API):

- [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/?view=azps-6.2.1)
- [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-reference-for-monitor)
- [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/)

This is the example to create a CPU% metric alert on a classic VM:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/powershell-samples#create-metric-alerts

```
# Create an Email action
$actionEmail = New-AzAlertRuleEmail -CustomEmail myname@company.com

# Create a Webhook action
$actionWebhook = New-AzAlertRuleWebhook -ServiceUri https://example.com?token=mytoken

# Create the alert rule on the CPU% metric on a classic VM
Add-AzMetricAlertRule -Name vmcpu_gt_1 -Location "East US" -ResourceGroup myrg1 -TargetResourceId /subscriptions/s1/resourceGroups/myrg1/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/my_vm1 -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 1 -WindowSize 00:05:00 -TimeAggregationOperator Average -Action $actionEmail, $actionWebhook -Description "alert on CPU > 1%"

# Retrieve the alert rule
Get-AzAlertRule -Name vmcpu_gt_1 -ResourceGroup myrg1 -DetailedOutput
```

Additional Azure Monitor PowerShell Resources:

- [Microsoft Docs: Azure Monitor PowerShell samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/powershell-samples)
- [Microsoft Docs: Create, view, and manage metric alerts using Azure Monitor > PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric#with-powershell)
- [Microsoft Docs: Create, view, and manage log alerts using Azure Monitor > PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log#managing-log-alerts-using-powershell)
- [Microsoft Docs: Create, view, and manage activity log alerts by using Azure Monitor > PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-activity-log#powershell)